# MVVM Add to favourites functionality

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm

I am implementing an "Add to favourites" functionality in a detail screen. If the user taps the FAB, I want to set the fab as selected and update my database. How could I use the same value that I am sending to the database to be used in my fragment (to be consistent, in case there is some issue while updating the DB)

**Fragment**

```
class BeerDetailsFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_beer_details) {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<BeerDetailsViewModel>()

    private val args by navArgs<BeerDetailsFragmentArgs>()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        subscribeToObservers()
        viewModel.getBeer(args.beerId)
    }

    private fun subscribeToObservers() {
        viewModel.beer.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { resource ->
            when(resource.status) {
                Status.SUCCESS -> {
                    loadData(resource.data)
                }
                Status.ERROR -> {
                    showError(resource.message)
                }
                Status.LOADING -> {}
            }
        })
    }
    
    private fun loadData(beerDetails: BeerDomainModel?) {
        if (beerDetails != null) {
            Glide.with(requireContext())
                .load(beerDetails.imageMedium)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_beer)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_beer)
                .fallback(R.drawable.ic_beer)
                .into(beerDetailsImage)

            beerDetailsName.text = beerDetails.name
            beerDetailsDescription.text = beerDetails.description

            fab.isSelected = beerDetails.isFavourite

            fab.setOnClickListener {
                viewModel.updateBeer(beerDetails)
                // I shouldn't do it like this in case there is an issue while updating the DB
                fab.isSelected = !beerDetails.isFavourite
            }
        }
    }
...
```

**View Model class**

```
class BeerDetailsViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(private val repository: BreweryRepository) : ViewModel() {

    private val beerId = MutableLiveData<String>()

    fun getBeer(id: String) {
        beerId.value = id
    }

    var beer = beerId.switchMap { id ->
        liveData {
            emit(Resource.loading(null))
            emit(repository.getBeer(id))
        }
    }

    fun updateBeer(beer: BeerDomainModel) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.updateBeer(beer)
        }
    }
}
```

**Repository**

```
class BreweryRepository @Inject constructor(private val breweryApi: BreweryApi, private val beerDao: BeerDao, private val responseHandler: ResponseHandler) {

...

    suspend fun getBeer(id: String): Resource<BeerDomainModel> {
        return try {
            withContext(IO) {
                val isInDB = beerDao.isInDB(id)
                if (!isInDB) {
                    val response = breweryApi.getBeer(id).beer.toDomainModel()
                    beerDao.insert(response.toBeerEntity())
                    responseHandler.handleSuccess(response)
                } else {
                    val beer = beerDao.get(id).toDomainModel()
                    responseHandler.handleSuccess(beer)
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            responseHandler.handleException(e)
        }
    }

    suspend fun updateBeer(beer: BeerDomainModel) {
        withContext(IO) {
            val dbBeer = with(beer) {
                copy(isFavourite = !isFavourite)
                toBeerEntity()
            }
            beerDao.update(dbBeer)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to use a unidirectional flow with the following implementation:

Not sure how is your *DAO* implemented, but if you are using **Room** you could update your get method to return a `Flow` instead. That way whenever your data is updated, you will get back the updated data.
Then in your VM you just get that `Flow` or stream of data and subscribe to the updates. `Flow` has a very convenient method: `asLiveData()` so your code will look much cleaner.

If you are not using Room, then what I'd do is either construct a `Flow` or some type of stream and on updates successful updates send out the new data.

Comment: Thanks, I will consider that for the future. But for now, I only have a few more hours to get this done and I am not capable of changing the whole implementation since I've never used Flows before and I would need to learn how to do it first.

Comment: Than probably I'd either use the same resource pattern like with the get or send back a boolean, then update the beer in VM based on the returned information. If you don't want many modifications and don't mind the loading indicator however, just call `getBeer` again.